# D3 week of the year error?

Tags: d3.js

I'm writing an app that uses some d3. I had some issues so I tried to debug a bit and found this in chrome's interactive shell

```
d3.time.format("%W/%Y")(new Date(d3.time.format("%W/%Y").parse("53/2015")))
```

returns

```
01/2016
```

I'm using version 3.5.16 of D3. Am I doing something wrong or missing something cause that does look weird.(and 2015 has 53 weeks for [reference](http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2016)) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%W is zero-indexed, so you're referencing the 54th week of the year there, not the 53rd.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

(only a leap year that starts on a sunday can span 54 separate mon-sun periods)